# How do i change number into string

Tags: excel, vba

How do i change any number in my rows or cell into "o++". I have 20 rows which is full with characters and numbers. Any rows start with number like 13444 i want it convert it to 0++ and anything else with character for ex. WWWWE , just keep it as it is. here is my code. in my code i didn't show few steps,  i just showed you guys lil ex. SO MY QUESTION is do i used cell = ISNUMERIC or  ISNUMBER OR there is any other value i can i set up for integers. isnumeric and isnumber kept on giving me error ARGUMENT NOT OPTIONAL

```
 Sub con()
    dim cell as range, ss as string
      ss = "o++"
       set cell = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i)
           If cell = IsNumeric Then
              Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A" & b).Value = ss

           else
```

Comment: You cannot write `If cell = IsNumeric Then`.  The correct syntax is `If IsNumeric(cell) Then`.  `IsNumeric` is a Boolean function (that is, it returns True or False) and `cell` is its parameter.  Look up functions to understand what you are doing wrong.

Comment: thanks its working now @TonyDallimore ..... but now its counting empty rows as a number too thats what i did with my code  ElseIf IsNumeric(cell) Then
   
   Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A" & b).Value = 0++ and now any rows has empty value counting as numeric and adding 0++ instead of be a blank cell.

Comment: I have never understood why an empty cell counts as numeric; one of life's mysteries.  Have an outer `If` to check if the cell contains something.  `IsEmpty(Cell)` is another Boolean function.  `Cell.Value = ""` is another possibility.

Comment: Just noticed.  What are `i` and `b`?

Comment: i and b is a variable for my loop so i have to define IsEmpty(cell) that's what you mean

Comment: I cannot see any loops that are setting `i` and `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Is Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
  If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
    ' Process numeric cell
  End If
End if
```

**Edit** `cell` is a Range. The default property of a Range it is Value.  I prefer to be explicit and not rely on defaults.  I only noticed I had omitted `.Value` when I wrote the comment below. I had written `.Value` there are I do not like being inconsistent without an explanation.

Comment: Tony, note that `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber` returns FALSE for both empty cells and numbers stored as text.

Comment: @DougGlancy.  What is the relevance of `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber`?  `IsNumeric` returns True for a number stored as text.

Comment: I think it better addresses your desire for a function that returns FALSE for an empty cell. Regarding a number stored as text there might be cases when you don't want it seen as a number by your code, so I was just pointing out an additional possible advantage of IsNumber. I thought it might be of interest.

Comment: Sorry but I do not agree. The OP does not know the syntax for `IsNumeric`.  I think introducing worksheet functions is a step too far.

Comment: No need to apologize. To clarify, I thought would be of interest to you in light of your "life mystery" above. I feel like I've managed to annoy you instead :)

Comment: @DougGlancy Not offended; confused. I had not linked `WorksheetFunction.IsNumber` with my remark about life's mysteries.  When I learnt programming 45 years ago, we were taught that our applications had to be intuitive with no hidden side effects.  I do not consider `IsNumeric` treating empty as numeric to be intuitive.  I should not be surprised. Bill Gates clearly did not go to the same school as me; most Microsoft applications are unintuitive and full of hidden side effects.

Comment: @DougGlancy  On a secondary issue, I have recently discovered that some worksheet functions are slower than their VBA equivalents.  For example, `Transpose` is much slower than a pair of nested For-Loops.  Today I would not recommend a worksheet function until I had checked its performance.

Comment: @TonyDallimore I added isnumeric but its only counting cells with entire number... as long as first character is number i want it to change it to string and that's what i used If IsNumeric.Formula.Left(cell, 1) Then ..... but that's giving me error .... is there any other way i can count only first ch as isnumeric

Comment: Again wrong syntax for VBA.  `If IsNumeric(Left(cell.Value, 1)) Then`.  `Left` is a string function that returns the start of a longer string.  This short string then becomes a parameter for the Boolean function IsNumeric.

Comment: thanks im new at vba... where do i find all the syntax for vba ... is there any tutorial... once again thanks

Comment: @user3795861  Search the web for "Excel VBA Tutorial".  There are many to choose from so try a few then finish the one that works for you.  I prefer books.  I visited a large library, reviewed all the Excel VBA Primers then borrowed the most promising two or three to try at home. I bought the one I preferred which I still check from time-to-time.